# I am trying to create an NDVI image using an RSGISLib python script, but it is displaying no data values

Tags: python, ndvi

My script runs fine and creates an output, but the output is displaying values all the way down to -999, rather than just having the values present in the NDVI result (0-1). I can create an NDVI image from this, but it requires some tweaking within a GIS program, which i'd rather not have to do as i have to process a large number of images. Is there anything i can add to the script so this stops happening?

This is the script

```
import rsgislib
import rsgislib.imagecalc
import rsgislib.imagecalc.calcindices

InImg = './LS5TM_19890814_lat55lon10028_r22p34_vmsk_rad_srefdem.kea'
OutImg = './Manitoba1989'
ndviImg = OutImg+ '_ndvi.tif'

rsgislib.imagecalc.calcindices.calcNDVI(InImg, 3, 4, ndviImg, stats=True, gdalFormat='GTIFF')
```

Comment: Are you sure band 3 and 4 are red and nir?

Comment: Pretty sure, this is a landsat 5 image.

Comment: NDVI values are between [-1, 1]. -999 values  can be attributable to nodata values. See that in module documentation.